# how to use like operator in array laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to add `Like` operator in array but it gives me error:

> Unknown column '0' in 'where clause (`admin_id` = 2 and `0` = name and `Like` = %zdgbdsh%) order by `id` asc limit 10 offset 0)

Here is my query:-

```
$conditions = array();
if(!empty($data['name'])) {
    $conditions = array_merge($conditions,array('name','Like'=>'%'.$data['name'].'%'));
}
```

And here is my final query:-

```
$querys = DB::table('users')
         ->where($conditions)
         ->skip($iDisplayStart)->take($iDisplayLength)
         ->OrderBy($orderby,$dir)
          ->get();
```

Note: I don't want directly in query like

```
where('users.name','like','%'.$data['name'].'%');**
```

I want to do in conditions variable 
I am using laravel framework 5.2

Answer (score 0):

This is not the greatest way of applying multiple conditions, But you can always user the whereRaw

so loop through a array with your conditions eg.

```
$conditions = [];
if (!empty($data['name'])) {
   $conditions = array_merge(
       $conditions,
       ["name LIKE '%".$data['name']."%'"]
   );
}

$query = DB::table('users');

// apply add raw conditions
foreach($conditions as $condition){ $query->whereRaw($condition); }

$query->skip($iDisplayStart)->take($iDisplayLength)
      ->OrderBy($orderby,$dir)
      ->get();
```

you could also find some packages that will help you out with things like this.

Hope it helps

Comment: this works for me 

$test = \DB::table('users');
$test->whereRaw("email like '%test%'");
$results = $test->get();

try breaking your query down and removing the skip and take to see if that helps so we can define where its breaking

Comment: i have do debugging but it gives me error on this line ["name LIKE '%".$data['name']."%'"]

Comment: bro i already put semicolon that was not issue problem is in our code :(

Comment: i have execute this query but this gives me empty result $query = User::where(['city'=>'Ludhiana','users.mobile'=> 'Like %'.'872'.'%'])->get();
        $query  = json_decode(json_encode($query),true); 
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($query); die;

Comment: $query = User::where('city', 'Ludhiana')->where('mobile', 'LIKE', '%872%')->get();

Comment: iknow this will work but i want to execute this query in array

Comment: you have used two where but i want to execute in one where clause

Comment: you will have to deconstruct the array in a loop or something

Comment: $users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereColumn([
                    ['first_name', '=', 'test'],
                    ['updated_at', '>', 'somedate']
                ])->get(); Then try something like this

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$conditions=array_merge($conditions,array('name' => 'Like %'.$data['name'].'%'));
```

#### Update

I've just realised that will produce `name = Like %data%`

You can change it to:

```
$conditions=array_merge($conditions,array('name', '%'.$data['name'].'%'));
```

and in where use:

```
->where(join(' LIKE ', $conditions))
```

Comment: now no error comes but my data is not fetched it gives me empty result :(

Comment: i have serached to matched records but no data will  fetched

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `admins`.`username` as `hod`, `states`.`state` as `userState` from `users` inner join `admins` on `users`.`admin_id` = `admins`.`id` inner join `states` on `users`.`state_id` = `states`.`id` where (`admin_id` = 2) and `2` is null order by `id` asc limit 10 offset 0)